# Angular - an overlay component that is shown/hidden like a tooltip

Tags: angular, tooltip, overlay

I am using an overlay from https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/examples
and display/ hide the overlay with event form related element

for exampple : `(mouseenter)="isOpen=true"  (mouseleave)="isOpen=false"`

but if the mouse moved from the related element to the overlay, overlay auto hides...
so I need to add more events to display the overlay.

is there any easy way to bind an overlay to element like a tooltip,
that the overlay will shown while mouse is over element or overlay

Here is my current solution, but it is not obvious, and not reusable:

TS:

```
  private _currentOver : boolean;
  public get currentOver() : boolean {
    return this._currentOver;
  }
  public set currentOver(v : boolean) {
    if(v)this._currentOver = v;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this._currentOver= v;
    }, (1000));
  }
  
  private _currentInfoOver : boolean;
  public get currentInfoOver() : boolean {
    return this._currentInfoOver;
  }
  public set currentInfoOver(v : boolean) {
    if(v)this._currentInfoOver = v;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this._currentInfoOver= v;
    }, (1000));
  }
 public  get currentIsOpen():boolean {return this.currentInfoOver || this.currentOver} ;
```

HTML:

```
<a  (mouseenter)="currentOver=true"  (mouseleave)="currentOver=false" cdkOverlayOrigin #trigger="cdkOverlayOrigin">
    <div >        
        .........
    </div>
</a>
</div>
<ng-template   
cdkConnectedOverlay
[cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="trigger"
[cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="currentIsOpen"
>
<div   (mouseenter)="currentInfoOver=true" (mouseleave)="currentInfoOver=false">
 ............
</div>
</ng-template>
```